# Code Review — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion, swag

If your name is on the first two pages of [this page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) as of Site Graduation you'll be hearing from me soon... **but that's good news!** <sub><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>this time</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub>
We want to send you a little care package, as a token of our appreciation for being awesome and making this site the success it has become! Inside this little box, you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!** — [the tagline has been decided on, and we're sticking with the tagline "Making code slightly less wrong."](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6434/69261)

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

**AN AWESOME RUBBER DUCK!**

[image: A RUBBER DUCK!!!!!!! ZOMG!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you at some point this week: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do so, after which, I'll close it and take care of sending all of these wonderful items your way! <s>I'm not gonna offer a precise prediction</s> It'll take *precisely* between 42 and 56 days for these to arrive at your doorstep.

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such.

**Thanks to all of you for making this site awesome!**

Comment: Question about the duck: is it *actually* rubber, or is it one of those fake-rubber ones?

Comment: Is the t-shirt available in other colors?

Comment: @Mat'sMug No: we just print a single model of shirt per site.

Comment: @EBrown i think they mix two rubbers: rubber and fake-rubber and make semi-rubber-semi-fakerubber duck.

Comment: So are we still going with "Making code slightly less wrong" as a tagline then?

Comment: @Paweł I accept your compromise.

Comment: @Zak i will post question on meta about tagline, so everyone can suggest something and vote.

Comment: _be sure to fill out **the form** as soon as you're able to do so_ <- do you mean that you will send the form to each of us as a private message in a short time?

Comment: @Caridorc They have your e-mail address.

Comment: @Mast Perfect, I had forgotten about it.

Comment: Hey wait a minute... *no mug?*

Comment: The email address I have linked to my account isn't an address I use anymore and I'm afraid I'd miss something so I changed the email address of my account. Can this cause a problem right now?

Comment: @Mat'sMug That's one thing I was really hoping for too :(

Comment: @TopinFrassi No, I will be pulling the addresses today ;) Regardless: **anyone who is on those two pages and does not receive an e-mail, please let me know.**

Comment: @syb0rg Same here. Mugs are *the* top of the swag :o

Comment: If you put the stickers in the dishwasher (or in the rain, in case of the car), do they come off? If not, we can make our own mugs =) (though they won't be the "real thing")

Comment: Please note that the concept of `first two pages of this page` is not as precise as one would like it to be. On the non-mobile website, it goes up to EBrown (with 5355); on the mobile website (and on the mobile app), it goes up to jonrsharpe (10.1k).

Comment: @Josay The top 72 users is what it is supposed to mean ;)

Comment: ERRRRRR MERRRRRR GERHHHHHHDDDDDD!!!!!!! IT'S A RUBBERDUCK!

Comment: The printing on the t-shirt will (can?) be closer to the neck?

Comment: V-necks you say? Good idea; everyone loves v-neck Tees.

Comment: @Shog9: Not really, I hate V-necks :) Currently the printing seems to be on the belly.

Comment: Hey JNat, I don't seem to have received an email?

Comment: @Flambino I just checked, and I did send you the e-mail. I'll resend it, though.

Comment: Thanks - turns out I'd been searching in the wrong mailbox... apologies for the inconvenience. But now I have two emails, so that's double the swag, right? ;)

Comment: @Flambino No ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Darn... thought I'd found a loophole

Comment: That shirt would look better in black !

Comment: plus 1 for the idea and +10 for the TESLA =D

Comment: I just received my swag :D! I'm so happy! Here is me with it [swag yeah](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2BoLn.jpg)

Comment: Greetings, I received my shirt ;) Real life took away my focus on internet points, but I am glad I was part of this community! Also wearing the shirt proudly right now ;]

Comment: I just got my swag too! +1!

Comment: Just got mine today!

Comment: I received mine as well. Thanks a lot! but what do I do with my other 12 cars ? They can't have a sticker ;-)

Comment: we need more ducks.

Answer (score 15):

I don't want to seem ungrateful in any way, but would it be possible to have a choice between a Code Review mug and the Code Review Rubber Duck?  It could be an option on the form we fill out for example.

I just see myself using a mug more than a rubber duck, and I don't have kids to give it to.

Comment: Many have already filled out the form, it's too late to choose - just send us a mug anyway!

Comment: KIDS!? No way that my kids, even if I would have had some, would get to play with my rubber duck!

Comment: I'm going to do the same thing with the duck that I'd do with a mug--set it on my desk at work.

Comment: Pour hot coffee in the duck.

Comment: I think Rubber Ducking will serve me better in work than Mugging will.

Comment: No, sorry :\ Most sites only get two swag items, and for those that get a third item, the third one is supposed to be really special and not something that would make sense regardless of the logo that's stamped on it — hence, the duck :)

Comment: @Morwenn I pour hot coffee into myself every day. It's the best way to make a duck productive.

Comment: @RubberDuck At some point when you're too used to pour coffee into yourself, it doesn't make anything anymore :/

Answer (score 4):

Are the stickers going to be washable, that is, if I put a sticker on my mug, then put the mug in the dishwasher, will the sticker get damaged?

If I slap a sticker on my Tesla (I don't have one, but you seem to suggest you can slap one on there with the image), and it rains, does the sticker get damaged? Can I drive my car with stickers through the carwash?

Comment: `Can I drive my car with stickers through the carwash?` Sorry, no because you can **only stick them on a Tesla** as it is clearly shown and you don't have one.

Comment: The stickers are printed on vinyl and laminated so they should hold up pretty well. That being said, I would not recommend putting them in the dishwasher. The stickers are also removable/repositionable, so my guess is they have the potential to come off during a car wash/dishwash.